# Orientdb query and scheme patterns to speed up the reading phase

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've some performance issue on a quite big data store.
For optimizing the insert phase, we created a document store and not a graph, infact the edge creation performance was too slow.
 Essentially now we have a class A (with about 30M documents) with a link (say field fieldL) to a class B (about 500 documents).
The query structure is like:

**select from A where field1='field1value' and field2='field2value' and field3>0 ... and fieldL in (select from B where ...)**

The first issue i've found is this:
I've created n indexes on the n properties engaged in the where condition, but the explain command showed me orient uses only one... https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3626
So I've created a composite index and  if I perform a query involving only the index, say

**select from A where field1='field1value' and field2='field2value' and field3>0** 
the result is really fast

The issue is about the second part of the query, involving the fieldL and the links.
I've tried with the [#rid,...] syntax but it seems not perform well.

I've also tried to change the schema using a different approach: class B with multiple links to class A, using a different query pattern (say the field containing the links fieldL1):

**select * from (select expand(fieldL1) from B where ...) where  field1='field1value' and field2='field2value' and field3>0**

In this case the subquery executes a sort of partition of the data, but unfortunatelly we lose the indexes on the result set, so we have really slow performances on the second where clause (field1='field1value' and field2='field2value' and field3>0).

**My question is: Does it exist a better query pattern to execute these kind of query faster?**

Thank you very much.

By the way during the performance tuning it seems really awkward to perform a count of the documents involved in a query.  (https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3462)

Comment: [Update] I think this is the right point to start http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Time-series-use-case.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following query

```
select * from (select expand(fieldL1) from B where ...) where field1='field1value' and field2='field2value' and field3>0
```

it doesn't use the index because seems that there are problems when using the subqueries and the indexes

For more information, you can look at this link 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/7jWEGpkIzXQ

Comment: Yes, I see the point, but which are the alternatives?  I think I must change the schema to optimize the search, but how?